# Transposing a matrix in C++

Tags: c++, matrix, transpose

I'm writing a program to transpose a given matrix using allocated memory. The function works perfect with square matrix NxN (rows==cols) but it crashes with MxN matrix (rows != cols). Please help

```
void transpose(int **matrix, int *row, int *col)
{
    // dynamically allocate an array
    int **result;
    result = new int *[*col]; //creates a new array of pointers to int objects
    // check for error
    if (result == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Error allocating array";
        exit(1);
    }
    for (int count = 0; count < *col; count++)
    {
        *(result + count) = new int[*row];
    }

    // transposing
    for (int i = 0; i<*row; i++)
    {
       for (int j = i+1; j<*col; j++)
       {
        int temp = *(*(matrix + i) + j);
        *(*(matrix + i) + j) = *(*(matrix + j) + i);
        *(*(matrix + j) + i) = temp;
       }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<*row; i++)
    {
       for (int j = 0; j<*col; j++)
       {
          *(*(result + i) + j) = *(*(matrix + i) + j);
          cout << *(*(result + i) + j) << "\t";
       }
       cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `new` throws an exception on failure. Use `new(nothrow)` if you want it to return `null` on failure (although it's unusual to want that).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lines:

```
for (int i = 0; i<*row; i++)
{
   for (int j = i+1; j<*col; j++)
   {
    int temp = *(*(matrix + i) + j);
    *(*(matrix + i) + j) = *(*(matrix + j) + i);
    *(*(matrix + j) + i) = temp;
   }
}
```

are the issue. The problem is that matrix is indexed by i then j, not j then i like you are doing in the second and third line in the while loop. Image that matrix is a 2x3 matrix, then you try to perform matrix[2][3] = matrix[3][2], but matrix[3][2] does not exist.

It is best to go about simply initializing result directly in this loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i<*row; i++)
   for (int j = 0; j<*col; j++)
     result[j][i] = matrix[i][j];
```

Then you can output like below, or delete matrix and reassign matrix to be result as you wish. My entire transpose function became the following code (row and col need not be pointers to int pass by value is just fine. Also accessing matrices should use array subscripts as it is nicer style):

```
void transpose(int **matrix, int row, int col)
{
  // dynamically allocate an array
  int **result;
  result = new int *[col]; //creates a new array of pointers to int objects
  for (int i = 0; i < col; i++)
    result[i] = new int[row];

  // transposing
  for (int i = 0; i<row; i++)
   for (int j = 0; j<col; j++)
     result[j][i] = matrix[i][j];

  //output resulting matrix
  for (int i = 0; i<col; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j<row; j++)
    cout << result[i][j] << "\t";
   cout << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: was it from your output statements? cause you need to make sure those loops similarly index result, instead of *row by *col those should be *col by *row

Comment: I added my entire transpose function which I tested

Comment: @pippin1289 do not forget to delete allocated memory

Comment: oh that is another question, i was going to ask if i need to deallocate that result array, in my textbook when they use a return function and they use allocated memory array, i dont see they call the `delete[] array` , but what i think is everytime we use `new` keyword for allocated memory array we need to deallocate it right?

Comment: Of course you will need to delete it. I was unsure of what you actually wanted from result. You could return it if you want to use it, or you could delete matrix and reassign to result. Either way when deleting a matrix you should iterate over the first array calling delete[] for each subarray, then finsih with a delete[] on the overall matrix.

Comment: for the above function the result is just to hold the array and then print it out like exactly the codes are doing, I also have another functions that return pointers and in these functions I also created a new dynamic memory array. So do I need to deallocate them in both kind of functions `void` and `**int` ?

Comment: If you are returning a pointer you can't deallocate the memory in the function or you will return garbage memory or null. If you do not return any value, you should most definitely deallocate the memory within the function. Just be careful on functions returning newly allocated memory to be sure to delete them when they are no longer in use.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to transpose matrix "in place" :

> *(*(matrix + i) + j) = *(*(matrix + j) + i);

you shouldn't do this. If count of columns is greater then count of rows, allocated for `matrix`, you'll read and write non-allocated memory.

IMHO, It would be better to store whole matrix in continuous memory. Not in different pieces. In this manner the code would look like this:

```
void transpose( int *matrix, int row, int col )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < row; i++ )
    {
       for ( int j = i + 1; j < col; j++ )
       {
           int temp = matrix[ i * col + j ];
           matrix[ i * col + j ] = matrix[ j * col + i ];
           matrix[ j * col + i ] = temp;
       }
    }
}
```

The only minus of this allocation, that you can't address an element like `matrix[ i ][ j ]` but only `matrix[ i + col + j ]`. Pluses are: 1) easy to allocate/deallocate memory (just `matrix = new int[ col * row ]` and `delete [] matrix`) 2) a little bit faster access to elements (because of continuous location of them)

At the end, I think, that it would be the best way to look at `std::vector`. If you want, I can show you, how will you function look with vector

Comment: yea thanks for your input, i have been told many times that using vector is much better but for this problem im required to use this concept :(